# Definite Integral of a derivative

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am doing a differential equation for my physics class, and I have gotten to 
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t)\right]=-g e^{\text{kt}}$$ 
and just want to perform a definite integral. 
$$\int_{v_y(0)}^{v_{y}(t)} d\left[e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t)\right]=\int_{0}^{t} -g e^{\text{kt}} \, dt$$

When the derivative is undone by the integral, which variable do I evaluate for the bounds on the left integral?

Comment: you must take integral on the same interval on both side otherwise you dont have equality

Answer (score 1):

It's simply

$$\int_{v_{y_0}}^{v_{y}} d\left[e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t)\right]=(e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t))\big |_{t=v_{y_0}}^{t=v_{y}}$$
Like in
$$\int_a^b dx^x=(x^x)\big |_a^b=b^b-a^a$$

Normally you should have
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t)\right]=-g e^{\text{kt}}$$
$$\int_0^t d(e^{\text{kt}} v_y(t))=-\int_0^tg e^{\text{kt}}dt$$

Comment: Which of the variables is evaluated, $v_y$ or t, is my question.

Comment: t the rest are costants like $\int d(2x^4)$ @BrandonMyers

Answer (score 1):

Your bounds on the left are wrong.

Assuming $k \ne 0$ and $g$ are constant regarding time, we have
$$
\frac{d}{dt} \left(e^{kt} v_y(t)\right) = -g\,e^{kt} \iff \\
\left[ e^{k\tau} v_y(\tau) \right]_{\tau=t_0}^{\tau=t} = 
-g \int\limits_{t_0}^t e^{k\tau} d\tau \iff \\
e^{kt} v_y(t) - e^{kt_0} v_y(t_0) = -\frac{g}{k}\left(e^{kt}-e^{kt_0}\right)
$$
where we integrate both sides over time (using a new integration variable $\tau$ to avoid a name clash with the upper bound) from $t_0$ to $t$.

Comment: Op 's integral is not correct he should have same interval of integration on both side

Comment: See my first line.

Comment: yep nice answer +1

Answer (score 0):

Call the variable $u(t,v_y) = e^{kt}v_y$, so the LHS of your last equation becomes

$$
\int_{u(0,v_{y_0})}^{u(t,v_{y})}{\rm d}u = u(t,v_{y}) - u(0,v_{y_0})
$$

That is, the variable is $u$