# How to evaluate the definite integral of a derivative?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

I am looking through some old material on first order differential equations and realized I didn't really understand how the bounds on the integral are found. I found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2703953/definite-integral-of-a-derivative) question from a couple years ago which gives an answer but doesn't really go into much detail. I'm currently just thinking about first order linear diff eq's of the form: $$\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y=f(x)$$
Finding the integrating factor is pretty straightforward: $$\mu(x)=e^{\int{P(x)dx}}$$
Which is multiplied to both sides: $$\mu(x)\left[\frac{dy}{dx}+P(x)y\right]=\mu(x)f(x)$$
And this simplifies to: $$\frac{d}{dx}(\mu(x)y)=\mu(x)f(x)$$
And this is where the trouble starts. This equation should be integrated on both sides over the same bounds to maintain equality: $$\int_a^b{\frac{d}{dx}(\mu(x)y)dx}=\int_a^b{\mu(x)f(x)dx}$$
The RHS is just a straghtforward definite integral. The LHS however is a little more complicated. The question I linked above has a couple responses suggesting an integration by substitution so doing something like $u=\mu(x)y$ and I guess turning the integral into $\int_{u(a)}^{u(b)}{u}du$ but I'm not sure if that is right.

This question was inspired partially by a practical issue I'm trying to solve involving an op-amp integrator and following the u substitution route leads to some things that don't make sense like the initial value of the output growing to infinity which shouldn't happen since I'm modeling a circuit that already was made and I know works as intended in real life.

The LHS in my model looks like this: $$\int_0^T{\frac{d}{dt}\left[e^{-\frac{t}{R_2C}}V_{out}(t)\right]dt}$$
And applying $$u=e^{-\frac{t}{R_2C}}V_{out}(t)$$ and the bounds:
$$a=u(0)=V_{out}(0)\quad\text{and}\quad b=u(t)=e^{-\frac{t}{R_2C}}V_{out}(t)$$
gives: $$\int_{u(0)}^{u(t)}{du}=u(t)-u(0)=e^{-\frac{t}{R_2C}}V_{out}(t) - V_{out}(0)$$
This is problematic because when $V_{out}(0)$ is added over to the RHS and the exponential term is multiplied across it will then have a positive exponent and grow this initial condition to infinity.

I don't believe I made a mistake up to this point but regardless of whether my derivation in this particular problem is correct or not the question still remains as to what the proper way to deal with the limits on integrals of this type is, both determining what appropriate limits are and how to evaluate them. Any help here is appreciated.

Edit: I realized I did make a mistake and lost a negative sign earlier causing that weird behavior. Corrected the model now has a decaying initial value which is in line with what I've seen from the actual circuit. I've left this up however because I am still interested in whether there is a more formal way of doing this integration since I'm aware that a lot of the methods taught in differential equations play fast and loose. If there is any nuances that I'm missing in this post or any corrections to anything I said I would still like to hear. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to solve an RC circuit charging problem - are you sure the integrating factor has a negative exponent? I would assume it would be of the form $\exp(\frac{1}{RC})$

Comment: Hi Andre the RHS is not zero and also very messy which is why I left it out. I realized that I did make an error causing that behavior and edited the post.

Comment: Dhanvi you are correct. I found an error in my derivation and made an edit above. The circuit is an integrating op-amp with an extra resistor in parallel with the capacitor which introduces a couple more terms.

Comment: Looking at the edit - what you have done is fine. Generally when encountering physical problems we tend to make implicit assumptions on continuity, differentiability and integrability of the function in question and convert it to solvable ODEs. There is a large body of theory that deals with why these methods work and which functions does it work on - best done in a dedicated course on differential equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could think of this as a $u$-substitution, but I think that's overcomplicating things.

More simply, the function $\dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\mu(x)y(x)\right]$ has the function $\mu(x)y(x)$ as an antiderivative (more or less by definition). The fundamental theorem of calculus says that if $f(x)$ has $F(x)$ as an antiderivative, then

$$
\int_a^b f(x) \, dx = F(b)-F(a) \, .
$$

Applying this to the function $\mu(x)y(x)$ directly gives the result:

$$
\int_a^b \dfrac{d}{dx}\left[\mu(x)y(x)\right] \, dx=\mu(b)y(b)-\mu(a)y(a)
$$

without any need to substitute.

(Also, in my experience sign errors in the exponent are incredibly common when solving first-order linear differential equations. Just be glad that you currently seem to have an even number of them.)

Comment: Thanks that's the answer I expected but between that sign error and another reference I had seen saying to treat y(x) as a constant for some reason I was doubting myself.